# Hammer.js - links not working on Android

Tags: javascript, php, android, html, hammer.js

Working on a project that uses Hammer.js. Everything is working fine on iPhone, however on Android the links in my footer aren't working on the pages that use Hammer.js. I'm using a php include for the footer so that it swipes as part of the panel. What's weird is they don't even highlight like something that is linked would highlight when you touch the link (as a dead or placeholder href="#" link would behave). They simply behave like static text. Has anyone seen this before?

Hammer.js list from main .php file:

```
<li class="pane8">
    <div class="my-class">
        <h2>Header</h2>
        <h3>My subhead</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="img/myimage.jpg">
    </div>
    <div id="somecontent">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.             
    </div>
    <?php include("footer.php"); ?>
</li>
```

Contents of footer.php:

```
<div id="footer">
    <p class="follow-us">&mdash; Follow Us &mdash;</p>
    <span style="display: inline-block;">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/"  target="_blank"><img src="img/footer-facebook.png" width="40" height="37"></a>
    </span>
    <span style="display: inline-block;">
        <a href="http://twitter.com/#!/" target="_blank"><img src="img/footer-twitter.png" width="40" height="37">
        </a>
    </span>
    <span style="display: inline-block;">
        <a href="http://www.youtube.com/" target="_blank"><img src="img/footer-youtube.png" width="40" height="37">
        </a>
    </span>
    <span style="display: inline-block;">
        <a href="http://instagram.com/" target="_blank">
            <img src="img/footer-instagram.png" width="40" height="37">
        </a>
    </span>
    <p>
        &copy; 2014 some company Inc. 
        <a href="privacy.php">Privacy Statement/Your Privacy Rights</a>
        <br />
        <a href="privacy.php#cookies">Internet Based Ads</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="terms.php">Terms &amp; Conditions</a>
   </p>
</div>
```

Comment: do you have any JS examples of what you defined? 
where are the events? 
calling "include" is impossible not to work.
There must be an error in JS that makes everything fall apart

Comment: also if you wanna use something better (I recently dropped hammer from my builds) use this: http://quojs.tapquo.com/

Comment: So after a little troubleshooting, I found that it's not just the footer include that's displaying this behavior. If I put a normal 'code'<a href="www.google.com">Something</a>'code' in the body of a hammer.js slide, the link doesn't work on Android, but works in iPhone. There is nothing special about that link, the text is showing fine, but it won't link on Android.

Comment: We ended up using a tap event with hammer to link to the other urls. Not elegant, but it works in the short term. I would be interested to see if anyone else has a real fix so that I can use the clean way <a href="#">

Comment: ^ Even this is still intermittent. Doesn't always register the tap event. Starting to get why you don't use @Pian0_M4n...

Comment: switch now before you get white hairs. You will get them!